# To extract Audit event information from .evtx file of Window log

Tags: windows, powershell, audit, logparser

I have a window log file with extension .evtx, since it has huge information stored. I want to extract the events related to Audit which is activated for few of the folders. Command which can work in Powershell or Log Parser will be helpful. Open for other methodology to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

Get-WinEvent seems to do what you need:

```
Get-WinEvent -Path 'c:\ps-test\Windows PowerShell.evtx'
```